# Intel XDK - Work with a Demo - Option is empty

Tags: java, android, html, ide, intel-xdk

I have started development with Intel XDK.

I was very happy in the provided demos & interesting templates along with the Intel XDK software.

But after a week, most of the built-in templates are missing.

Rich collection of built-in demos is empty.

[image]

I have tried a complete re-installing of Intel-XDK. But it didn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: What version of Intel XDK are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The samples distributed by Intel XDK are only available when an active internet connection is used by the tool. Restarting Intel XDK or your machine may resolve the issue. If that doesn't work, I recommend visiting the Github repositories where the samples are maintained and stored at https://github.com/gomobile.